# Memory usage of Docker containers

Tags: memory, resources, cpu-usage, measurement, docker

I am using Docker to run some containerized apps. I am interested in measuring how much resources they consume (as far as regarding CPU and Memory usage).

Is there any way to measure the resources consumed by Docker containers like RAM & CPU usage?

Thank you.

Comment: for line in `docker ps | awk '{print $1}' | grep -v CONTAINER`; do docker ps | grep $line | awk '{printf $NF" "}' && echo $(( `cat /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/docker/$line*/memory.usage_in_bytes` / 1024 / 1024 ))MB ; done

Answer (score 111, accepted):

You can get this from `docker stats` e.g:

```
$ docker stats --no-stream
CONTAINER           CPU %               MEM USAGE / LIMIT   MEM %               NET I/O             BLOCK I/O             PIDS
6b5c0fcfa7d4        0.13%               2.203 MiB / 4 MiB   55.08%              5.223 kB / 648 B    102.4 kB / 876.5 kB   3
```

Comment: is there any way to measure max resource used by container at any particular time during its complete lifecycle?

Comment: @Khatri No easy way (at least that I know of). I think you'd have to use some monitoring solution e.g. prometheus and take samples.

Answer (score 16):

Update: See @Adrian Mouat's answer below as docker now supports `docker stats`!

There isn't a way to do this that's built into docker in the current version.  Future versions will support this via an api or plugin.

- https://github.com/dotcloud/docker/issues/36

It does look like there's an lxc project that you should be able to use to track CPU and Memory.

- https://github.com/Soulou/acadock-live-lxc

Comment: You can do this now with `docker stats`. I've added an answer, but you might want to update this one as well as it's the accepted one.

Answer (score 5):

Also, you can read resource metrics directly from cgroups.
See example below (I am running on `Debian Jessie` and `docker 1.2`)

```
> docker ps -q
afa03c363af5
> ls /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/system.slice/ | grep docker-afa03c363af5
docker-afa03c363af54815d721d938e01fe4cb2debc4f6c15ebff1851e20f6cde3ae0e.scope
> cd docker-afa03c363af54815d721d938e01fe4cb2debc4f6c15ebff1851e20f6cde3ae0e.scope
> cat memory.usage_in_bytes
4358144
> cat memory.limit_in_bytes
1073741824
```

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu, a couple of years after this, and I don't have a subfolder called `system.slice` - has it changed its name? There is now a `docker` subfolder at this level...

Comment: How about for Mac users?

Answer (score 4):

Kindly check out below commands for getting CPU and Memory usages of docker containers:-

`docker status container_ID`  #to check single container resources

[image]

`for i in $(docker ps -q); do docker stats $i --no-trunc --no-stream  ; echo "--------";done` #to check/list all container resources
[image]

`docker stats --all`   #to check all container resources live
[image]

`docker system df -v` #to check storage related information
[image]

Comment: Please [prefer text, not images/screenshots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Answer (score 2):

This is the command I use:

```
 docker stats CONTAINER_ID --no-stream --format "{{.Container}}: {{.MemUsage}}"
```

replace the CONTAINER_ID with the container id you find by using this command:

```
docker container ps
```