# Get cpu usage from Java API 1.13 for docker 1.1.2

Tags: docker, java

I am trying to obtain the amount of cpu (measured in time or percentage, any one) utilized by a specific container deployed using docker as:

```
docker run <container_name>
```

or using lxc as:

```
lxc-start -n <container_name>
```

I see that the container deployed using lxc has cpu usage statistics stored in `/sys/fs/cgroup/cpuacct/cpuacct.stat`

However, I want to obtain these stats using the java API that can be obtained from here:

https://github.com/docker-java/docker-java

I see that the API provides methods to start, stop containers, image information, etc. However, I don't see a way that can provide container statistics such as cpu, memory and other resource usage statistics. From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18956063/memory-usage-of-docker-containers) I see that this should have been present in API 1.0.

How do I get the cpu, memory, network and other resource usage statistics from the java API?

I would also very much appreciate an online blog or tutorial that can provide more insights into this too.

---

### Specifications:

**Docker:**

```
Client version: 1.1.2
Client API version: 1.13
Go version (client): go1.2.1
Git commit (client): d84a070
Server version: 1.1.2
Server API version: 1.13
Go version (server): go1.2.1
Git commit (server): d84a070
```

**Host OS:**

- Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty Tahr LTS
- Java 1.7

Comment: To get memory and CPU usage in Java code, see my answer here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45230004/how-to-get-docker-stats-detail-in-java-code/57986518#57986518](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45230004/how-to-get-docker-stats-detail-in-java-code/57986518#57986518)

Answer (score 1):

If you are still interested, the latest version of cadvisor (github.com/google/cadvisor) added support for networking, filesystem, and many other stats. Give it another try.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this API to monitor cpu and memory usage :
https://github.com/google/cadvisor

Comment: Is the docker java API itself not capable of doing this? And I would like to see an extensible Java API.

Comment: The docker api doesn't include easy way to monitor performance. But they still stock those information, see http://blog.docker.com/2013/10/gathering-lxc-docker-containers-metrics/ for more information. You can then write a small java library that would exploit those information.